# How to avoid going to new line with stdin in Rust

Tags: input, rust, line, stdin

I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let input = &mut String::new();

    loop {
        input.clear();
        print!("Your age: ");
        stdin.read_line(input);
        print!("{}", input);
    }
}
```

So when I input something, the programs returns "Your age:" plus my input. 
But when I run the program I don't want to write the input in a new line.
To do something like that in Python, I can write:

```
var = input("Your age: ")
```

How can I avoid going to a new line? I'm sure it's simple but I really can't realize how to do that, I tried a lot of different stuff...

Comment: Note that it would probably be more idiomatic to have `let mut input = String::new();` and then using `stdin.read_line(&mut input);`. It's a bit more verbose, but it's less weird than binding a temporary to a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flush `stdout` before reading the line:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let input = &mut String::new();

    loop {
        input.clear();
        print!("Your age: ");
        io::stdout().flush();
        stdin.read_line(input);
        print!("{}", input);
    }
}
```

From the [`print!` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print!.html):

> Note that stdout is frequently line-buffered by default so it may be necessary to use `io::stdout().flush()` to ensure the output is emitted immediately.